# OpenOffice Source Code Repository

Tags: svn, mercurial, repository

I found two links for OpenOffice Source code repository:

1. The svn repository is https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/ooo/trunk
2. The mercurial repository is at http://hg.services.openoffice.org/DEV300

Are they just clone to each other? Which one should I download to get the latest code?

Many thanks,
BR

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Getting_It#SCM_access_for_the_current_development_line_.28named_DEV300.29_using_Mercurial) the second link is the one you should be using. They moved from Subversion to Mercurial in October 2009.